# Amount of observations used to estimate GARCH model

Tags: estimation, garch

I was wondering, is there a rule of thumb for the number of observations used for the estimation of a GARCH model. Second, is more data always (or most of the time) better (in the sense that it leads to more accurate estimation of the parameters)?

Comment: You could see for yourself by simulating GARCH processes and estimating them using different samples sizes. "rugarch" package in R is well suited for the task as it has functions for estimation, rolling estimation and simulation of GARCH models.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what you are trying to achive. more data is not always good, because there could be structural change in the process, and if you use too much data, you will incorrectly include that in your calibration process.